# What is the difference between "versuchen" and "probieren"?

Tags: difference, verb

According to my Collins dictionary, both *versuchen* and *probieren* mean *to try*. Are they synonyms?

Comment: [Probier's mal mit Gemütlichkeit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yon4WqtMgh4) ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To expand on falkb's answer a bit: *versuchen* is usually followed by a complementary infinitive.  It means "try (to do something)."

> Ich **versuche**, Deutsch **zu lernen** aber ich finde es nicht einfach.

*Probieren*, on the other hand, is a transitive verb and takes a direct object in the accusative.

> Hast du **das Steak** bei Outback Steakhouse **probiert**?

*Probieren* also commonly appears with the separable prefix *aus-* (to try out).

> Nein.  Ich habe **es** noch nicht **ausprobiert**.

Answer (score 9):

`versuchen` is usually related to verbs (to attempt), `probieren` is more related to things you can see (to probe).

Comment: but remember `probieren` can be used always, but is a bit more colloquial speach

Answer (score 2):

For the record, in Yiddish the meanings are reversed: prubieren (synonym *pruven*) means to give something a try, as in "lomir (= lass uns) takkeh prubieren", let's give it a try; and versuchen means to try some food, as in "versuchen die suppe".

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are synonyms.

But there are a few exceptions, for example:

> I wanna try these delicious hamburgers. -> Ich möchte gerne diese köstlichen Hamburger probieren.

Here is the tendency to `probieren`, `versuchen` doesn't sound very nice here.

Comment: Yes, there's a tendency to *probieren*. But *versuchen* is also in use for meals and drinks.

Comment: Actually, there are a lot of "exceptions". All the following sentences are wrong, or at least very very odd: "Angeklagt wegen probierten Mordes", "er probierte zu fliehen", "sie hat probiert, den Fluss zu überqueren", "sie probierte sich als Model", "probiert sein etw. zu tun". All examples taken by just reading the Duden.

Comment: For me, "versuchen" is not quite synonymous to "probieren" - I find "probieren" to have a connotation that a failure would not be a (big) problem, while "versuchen" doesn't.

Comment: @Em1: Another regional/peer group/generation thing ... I would never ever use versuchen in context of food and I tell my students that it is wrong :)

Comment: @Emanuel Ich sag's auch nicht. Macht's aber nicht falsch. Aber es ist falsch, jemanden etwas als falsch zu lehren, wenn es zumindest eine signifikant große Gruppe gibt, die es sagt, so dass mindestens dem Duden der Eintrag der Bedeutung wert war.

Comment: @Em1: touché. Das ist wohl war.